# iOS - UIButton turns grey on showing action sheet and then blue on dismissing the action sheet

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I got a green button on the screen.

But on showing the action sheet , green button turns grey.

And when the action sheet is dismissed the button turns blue .

Code to show action sheet:

```
    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        //println("Cancelled")
    })


    self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Question**
Why the button is changing its background  color ? 
It's changing from original green color to grey color and then blur color .

Comment: what is the problem u facing , what the output you tried

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik button turns green on displaying action sheet and then turns blue

Comment: you want to update the button based on this `turns green on displaying action sheet and then turns blue`

Comment: is ur scenario like this?  clicking on the button should show action sheet

Comment: little confusing your question

Comment: guys : I don't want my button to change but it's changing . 
Button is changing with respect to the action sheet menu . How come it happen ?

Comment: can you attach some screen shot and some additional code of your VC

Comment: screenshot is a button on the screen : simple 
I am low on reputation to attach screenshot bbc

Comment: can you attach yur project ,

Comment: `[urButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]` have u added this?

Comment: @KoushikGounder - what the meaning of your command, in here we dont know the excat scenario

Comment: I think the user some how linked the button with his actionsheet so I just wanted him to make sure whether he used that button for invoking the action sheet or for some other action :-(

Comment: If he just created the button why is it changing color? and what outlet invokes the action sheet?

Comment: may be he changed the state of UIbutton on declaration

Comment: What you are seeing is default behavior of iOS. Try any default apps like mail, safari, messages, contacts, etc., and you'll observe the same.

Comment: you may want to check this answers

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behaviour.

You can avoid it by setting `tintAdjustmentMode` of UIButton to `UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal`.